# Debugging List<Class> object in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

```
Restaurant responseRestaurant = restaurant_repository.findById(1L);
List<Queue> responseQueueList = queue_repository.findByRestaurantId(responseRestaurant);
```

I have this code which returns the response in the form of a list , i want to check the value stored in "responseQueueList"

Comment: just mark breakpoint in at and just open Debug perspective to see when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse there is a Debug Mode

Maybe look into this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

But the point is you can put breakpoints on the left side of your code (also shown in the tutorial) and when the debbug mode gets to the breakpoint it stops executing.

Right of the Code window you see an other window with the prefix variables as soon a line of code is executed you can look there threw your variables and the values its containing.

Answer (score 2):

If the program is paused after the line that initializes `responseQueueList`, you can just mouse-over the word `responseQueueList` to see its value and the fields of the object it refers to (and its fields, and the objects they refer to, and their fields, etc...).

Eclipse won't show you the contents of the collection directly, but it will show you the fields, which you can look through (for example, `ArrayList`s store their contents in an array referenced by the field `elementData`).

If this is too inconvenient, you could also try adding `responseQueueList.toString()` in the Expressions view (either `Window -> Show View -> Expressions` or `Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Debug -> Expressions`)